Is that possible to reload the third-party Outlook VSTO add-in by program means or make the wrapper add-in triggering configuration reload?
I'm developing the Outlook VSTO add-in that interacts with the third-party Outlook VSTO add-in.
The third-party Outlook add-in is stateful and I can't force it to reload its configuration that was changed by my add-in.
I'd like to reload the third-party VSTO add-in from my add-in by program means when its configuration is changed. Is that possible?
Or may it be possible to create the wrapper add-in above the third-party add-in, which will disable the main add-in and call its ThisAddIn startup using the loaded DLL and attempt to trigger its configuration reload using DLL calls?
I tried to call the third-party add-in's loaded DLL, but failed to change the state of the loaded add-in. Tried to google, but unsuccessfully.

In general, you cannot do that. There are ways to load VSTO addins through a proxy in your code when you essentially play the role of the hosting app (Outlook) and load it using IManagedAddin::Load, but IManagedAddin::Unload won't necessarily do a complete cleanup.

Dmitry, is it possible to Load the third-party addin, then get access to it's memory, practically, to call the function refreshing state?

I don't think you can. IManagedAddin::Load will give you the IDTExtensibilioty2 interface. You cannot go to the underlying .Net object. You can try to unload the addin using IManagedAddin::Unload, but I am not sure how well that will work - I only ever used the former but not the latter.
